# Data not coming in dataset

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dataset

I want to display data in dataset on Button_click. Everything is fine. My query is working well in microsoft sql server 12 but data is not getting received in dataset when I am trying to run my application.

ASPX code

```
<tr>
<td><asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Search by Book Name" Font-Names="Tahoma" ForeColor="#3B5998"></asp:Label></td>
<td><asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
<td><asp:LinkButton ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Search" onclick="Button1_Click"/></td>     
</tr>

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
```

C# Code (code behind)

```
    scmd = new SqlCommand("select t.title 'Title', a.au_fname 'Author''s First Name', a.au_lname 'Author''s Last Name', p.pub_name 'Publication', t.price 'Price', t.notes 'Description' from titles t inner join authors a on t.au_id=a.au_id inner join publishers p on t.pub_id=p.pub_id where t.title like '%@ttl%';", scon);
    scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ttl",ttl);
    sda = new SqlDataAdapter(scmd);
    sda.Fill(ds, "grid");
    int cnt = ds.Tables["grid"].Rows.Count;

    if (cnt > 0)
    {
        GridView1.DataSource=ds.Tables["grid"];
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
    else
    {
        Label4.Text = "No Book With the given keyword found in our library.";
        Label4.Visible = true;
    }
```

Comment: Please format your code properly. Also, would be helpful if you posted your whole method (are you opening the conn properly?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand your question properly but,

still I think you need to change your code with

```
scmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ttl",ttl);
```

hope this is help full to you or give me some more information regarding your question